# Parametrization of manifold

Tags: calculus, parametrization

I need to find parametrization of following manifold. We have:
$$P=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2=4z\}$$
and line $L=\{(x,y,z):x=2,y=0\}$.

We lookk for manifold $M=\{(x,y,z)\in P:\operatorname{dist}((x,y,z),L)\leq1\}$, where $\operatorname{dist}$ is distance between given point and $L$.

Is there some standard equation for points which fulfill above condition?

Comment: Every point of $P$ is on the form $(x,y,\frac{x^2 + y^2}{4})$ and there are explicit formula for distance between these set of point and a line. I'm not sure you will get a manifold (you will have boundary and it might fail to be smooth).